# Why overloading works with inheritance in Java?

Tags: java, c++, inheritance

We know that overloading doesn't work for derived classes in C++. But why this behaviour is different in java? means why overloading works for derived classes in java ?
Consider below example from the FAQ's of Dr. Stroustrup

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Base
{
public:
    int f(int i)
    {
        cout << "f(int): ";
        return i+3;
    }
};
class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    double f(double d)
    {
        cout << "f(double): ";
        return d+3.3;
    }
};
int main()
{
    Derived* dp = new Derived;
    cout << dp->f(3) << '\n';
    cout << dp->f(3.3) << '\n';
    delete dp;
    return 0;
}
```

The output of this program is:

> f(double): 6.3
>
> f(double): 6.6

Instead of the supposed output:

> f(int): 6
>
> f(double): 6.6

But if we do this program in java then output is different.

```
class Base
{
    public int f(int i)
    {
        System.out.print("f (int): ");
        return i+3;
    }
}
class Derived extends Base
{
    public double f(double i)
    {
        System.out.print("f (double) : ");
        return i + 3.3;
    }
}
class Test
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Derived obj = new Derived();
        System.out.println(obj.f(3));
        System.out.println(obj.f(3.3));
    }
}
```

Comment: "We know that overloading doesn't work for derived classes in C++" : What do you mean exactly ? Also look for `virtual` method in C++, and their equivalent in Java ...

Comment: @quantdev I guess they mean the derived type "overload" actually *hides* the base class one.

Comment: Overloading happens in Java because of compile time polymorphism. The compiler decides which method should be called in case of a overloaded method at compile time itself.

Comment: @ManjunathAnand OK, but C++ also has compile time polymorphism, so there's got to be more to it :-)

Comment: The reference to Stroustrup's FAQ (http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#overloadderived) is interesting, because he explains very well that you can overload derived if you want, but you just have to tell the compiler.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It works because the Java Language Specification explicitly permits it in [§8.4.9. Overloading](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.9):

> If two methods of a class (whether both declared in the same class, or both inherited by a class, **or one declared and one inherited**) have the same name but signatures that are not override-equivalent, then the method name is said to be *overloaded*.

Also see [§15.12.2. Compile-Time Step 2: Determine Method Signature](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2).

Answer (score 7):

> You've said that *"We know that overloading doesn't work for derived
>   classes in C++"*.

It is not true or an accurate sentence. You can overload across base and derived classes in C++. Just need to `using` the parent's method into the derived class to *un-hide* that method.

```
class Derived : public Base
{
public:

    using Base::f;
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    double f(double d) { ... }
};
```

In Java overloaded (same name) method in the derived class doesn't hide its parent method and you don't need to explicitly bring it from the parent's method.